How do I make sure my Riemannian hessian is positive-definite?
I am working on L-BFGS optimization on a Grassmann manifold with a projector representation (not a point on the Stiefel manifold).
L-BFGS requires an initial hessian that is positive definite.
I have a model Euclidean hessian operator which is the candidate of the initial Euclidean hessian.
The initial Riemannian hessian can be generated from it according to 4.4 of this paper.
However, although this model Euclidean hessian is proved positive definite, I cannot guarantee the positive definiteness of its Riemannian counterpart in the tangent space.
May I have your suggestions on how to deal with it?
Specifically, if either of the following statements is shown to be true, I will be able to get along with my project.

The initial Riemannian hessian can be non-positive definite.
As long as some cautious techniques (such as truncated conjugate gradient which to some extent takes care of non-positive definiteness of the hessian) are taken, the iteration is very likely to converge at a minimum.
For manifolds adopting the metric of Euclidean inner product $\langle X, Y \rangle=\text{Tr}(X^\top Y)$, such as Grassmann manifold I am dealing with, the Riemannian hessian is positive definite as long as the Euclidean hessian is positive definite.

Thank you for any help.
